# Pandas concatenate values of all column into a new column list

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I am trying to concat all my columns into a new column. The concatenated values should be stored in a list.

**My dataframe:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1', '2', nan], 
                   'B': [nan, '5', nan], 
                   'C': ['7', nan, '9']})
```

desired output:

**df:**

```
A   B   C   concat_col
1   nan 7   [1,7]
2   5   nan [2,5]
nan nan 9   [9]
```

What i tried:

```
df['concat'] = pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.tolist()).str.join(',')
```

**Output i got:**

```
A   B   C   concat_col
1   nan 7   1,,7
2   5   nan 2,5,,
nan nan 9   ,,9
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
df['concat_col']=df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)
```

Comment: that worked! wondering why this doesnt work: `df['concat'] = pd.Series(df.dropna(axis=1).values.tolist()).str.join(',')`

Comment: because `df.dropna` will drop row or column containing nan, not only the value

Comment: Yep, when you use dropna on a dataframe, it will drop a row or column contain nan. When you use dropna on a row (as what I did when I used the apply method on my df), it drops the nan's in every row.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a list comprehension, taking advantage of the fact `np.nan != np.nan`:

```
df['D'] = [[i for i in row if i == i] for row in df.values]

print(df)

     A    B    C       D
0    1  NaN    7  [1, 7]
1    2    5  NaN  [2, 5]
2  NaN  NaN    9     [9]
```

Counter-intuitively, this is more efficient than Pandas methods:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)  # 8.25 s
%timeit [[i for i in row if i == i] for row in df.values]    # 55.6 ms
```

Comment: Interesting, that is way faster. Thanks for sharing

Comment: anyway with out using list comprehension ? @jpp

Comment: @pyd, Yes: `df.apply(lambda row: row.dropna().tolist(), axis=1)`.