# Combining columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
   c1   c2   c3
0   a   NaN  NaN
1  NaN   b   NaN
2  NaN  NaN   c
3  NaN   b   NaN
4   a   NaN  NaN
```

I want to combine these three columns like this :

```
    c4
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    b
4    a
```

**Here is the code to make the above data frame:**

```
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['a',np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,'a'],
    'c2': [np.NaN,'b',np.NaN,'b',np.NaN],
    'c3': [np.NaN,np.NaN,'c',np.NaN,np.NaN]
})
```

Comment: Try `a.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0] `

Comment: @cs95 I saw that ans too man and this is not exactly same !!!  (∩︵∩) !!!

Comment: Unfortunately it sort of is. Both questions call for collapsing non-null values into a single column. I didn't think to look for a duplicate until I started looking for the source to [Divakar's justify code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558215/python-justifying-numpy-array/44559180#44559180).

Comment: Nothing wrong with marking this question as duplicate - it is a _good_ thing, you are acting as a guidepost to other, more standard resources on the site. I am not "flagging" you, this is a privilege I am using as a member with more experience on the site :-)

Comment: Additionally, you've already received answers to your _own_ question, which doesn't always happen for a question marked duplicate, so that's a good thing! Did either of those answers work for you?

Comment: Others cannot provide me with more options if its marked duplicate

Comment: If you have any issue with the existing answers, please leave a comment and we'd get back ASAP. As for _new_ options, please take it from me they'll rehash the answers in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583174/how-to-collapse-columns-in-pandas-on-null-values), so I see no point in reopening. Last word on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bfill`ing is one option:

```
a.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]

0    a
1    b
2    c
3    b
4    a
Name: c1, dtype: object
```

---

Another one is a simple stack, gets rid of NaNs.

```
a.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True) 


0    a
1    b
2    c
3    b
4    a
dtype: object
```

---

Another interesting option you don't see everyday is using the power of NumPy. Here's a modified version of [Divakar's `justify` utility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56583373/4909087) that works with object DataFrames.

```
justify(a.to_numpy(), invalid_val=np.nan)[:,0]
# array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a'], dtype=object)

# as a Series
pd.Series(justify(a.to_numpy(), invalid_val=np.nan)[:,0], index=a.index)

0    a
1    b
2    c
3    b
4    a
dtype: object
```

Comment: stack is the better option IMO

Comment: @sammywemmy you know, `stack` is notorious for not performing great but when up against an even more inefficient row wise backfill... perhaps the winner.

Comment: I Agree ★⌒(●ゝω・)ｂTHX !!!!

Answer (score 4):

You could try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = pd.DataFrame({
    'c1': ['a',np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,'a'],
    'c2': [np.NaN,'b',np.NaN,'b',np.NaN],
    'c3': [np.NaN,np.NaN,'c',np.NaN,np.NaN]
})

newdf=pd.DataFrame({'c4':a.fillna('').values.sum(axis=1)})
```

Output:

```
newdf

  c4
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  b
4  a
```

I just see this option retrieved from [jpp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52507642/13676202), where jpp take advantage of the fact that `np.nan != np.nan` and uses a list comprehension, maybe it could be the fastest way:

```
newdf=pd.DataFrame({'c4':[i  for row in a.values for i in row if i == i]})
print(newdf)
```

Comment: This is a good option if it is guaranteed for rows to have at most one non-null column. +1

Comment: Yeah, that's true, thanks for noticing @cs95 and for the upvote too! :)