# python: combine two columns into one and duplicate corresponding cells

Tags: python

There's a dataframe with three columns:

```
    ID    col1    col2
0    item_1    abc    NaN
1    item_2    bcd    NaN
2    item_3    NaN    NaN
3    item_4    mnb    lkj
```

I would like to combine `col1` and `col2` like this:

```
    ID    col1
    item_1    abc
    item_2    bcd
    item_3    NaN
    item_4    mnb
    item_4    lkj
```

ID is not index but a column.

I tried with `stack().reset_index()` but this is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining columns of dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62751210/combining-columns-of-dataframe)

Comment: Try the second solution of @cs95

Comment: @MrNobody33 it is not helpful, it only messes all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it with stack.. the way you were trying it before -

1. Step 1 - `df.stack()` only the col1 and col 2 (and drop the Nans as well), then keep only the integer with `reset_index()`
   index that will be used to merge it in the next step
2. Step 2 - `pd.merge()`
   the initial DataFrame with the stacked one on their index
3. Step 3 - DONE!

```
a = pd.DataFrame(df[['col1','col2']].stack(dropna=True),columns=['col1']).reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
pd.merge(df[['ID']],a,how='left',left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

```
    ID  col1
0   item_1  abc
1   item_2  bcd
2   item_3  NaN
3   item_4  mnb
3   item_4  lkj
```

Do update the correct answer in case you find this easier to understand, for anyone finding similar solutions. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do that (in multiple steps, for clarity):

```
df.loc[df.col1.isna() & df.col2.isna(), "keep_as_na"] = True
df = df.melt(id_vars="ID").dropna()
df.loc[df.variable == "keep_as_na", "value"] = np.NaN
df.drop("variable", axis = 1).sort_values("ID")
```

The output is:

```
        ID value
0   item_1   abc
1   item_2   bcd
10  item_3   NaN
3   item_4   mnb
7   item_4   lkj
```

Comment: this one is rather entangled but works well on my data.

Comment: This method works but is too complex and has lots of unnecessary steps. Check my solution.